# How do I get typescript + webpack + vuejs to find packages in my node_modules/older/lib/ directory?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to turn an older typescript project into a library for a new vue.js project. The older package is configured to output to `./lib/` with `tsconfig.json`, and `package.json` includes all of the "this is where my library is" options I can think of. `tsc` compiles everything to `lib/` in the older package, and `npm link` is used to connect the packages together.

My problem is that no matter what I've tried, I can't seem to remove the `lib/` segment from my imports, like `import { baz } from "older/common/thing"` instead of `import { baz } from "older/lib/common/thing"`. Should I just live with it? Or is there something else I should be doing for prettier imports?

`package.json` (partial)

```
{
    "main": "./lib/index.js",
    "module": "./lib/index.js",
    "types": "./lib/index.d.ts",
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "typings",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "app/source/**/*",
    "test/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it but I think it is possible. The `import` is used by typescript and webpack, so you should tell typescript and webpack how to resolve these modules. Maybe with a code source / example somewhere, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is nigh impossible to remove the extra `/lib/` path when using es6 modules and a JavaScript build system on top of Typescript. One StackOverflow answer mentioned something about that feature being explicitly rejected from the ECMA standard. Instead, libraries like `lodash-es` build a second output that puts everything in the root directory of the package, adjacent to `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. Works for me since we probably need different build settings for the library and the application anyway.

I wound up putting a second `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` in `./lib/`, and just instructed `tsc` to pull the sources from `../app/source/`. The new program will `npm link` to the package name for the library instead of the application.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./",
    "rootDir": "../app/source",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
    "../app/source/**/*"
  ],
}
```